# Como mostrar todo el contenido de dos tablas en un select sin importar la cantida o tipo de campos

Tags: mysqli, sql

como podria yo mostrar todo el contenido de dos tablas mediante una sola consulta veran el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
<?php
     $query=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM 
                              comentarios c
                              RIGHT JOIN
                             notificaciones_evaluaciones n
                               ON n.id_post=c.post_id 
                             WHERE n.para='$id'
                            ORDER BY GREATEST(n.id_post,c.post_id)");
```

lo nececito para mostrar las notificaciones de comentarios y  me gusta juntos tales como las notificaciones de fb stackoverflow etc..

en realidad no tiene que haber ningun match entre los post_id por que en en realidad quiero mostrar todo el contenido de las dos tablas por lo tanto esto no resulta por que me traeria todas de una tabla y los matches de la otra lo que yo nececito es traer  todo de las dos tablas sin importar el tipo de campo u numeros por lo tanto `UNION` OR `UNIONALL` no me resultaria en este caso por que los campos varian un poco y el numero de campos no es igual.

intente con `FULL OUTER JOIN` pero me da el siguiente  error 
`error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN notificaciones_evaluaciones n ' at line 3`

alguien que me pueda dar una mano con lo que necesito hacer gracias!!

Comment: En MySQL no existe `FULL OUTER JOIN`, pero [se puede emular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/5587982), en caso de que sea eso lo que necesites. No sé, tampoco se entiende del todo la pregunta.

Comment: Para comprender lo que quieres, suponiedo que la tabla A tiene los registros A1, A2 y A3 y la tabla B los registros B1 y B2, ¿deseas un listado con las filas A1, A2, A3, B1 y B2? ¿o deseas combinarlos quedando las filas A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2, A3B1 y A3B2?